# Pycharm: Python can't open file pserve

Tags: pycharm, pyramid

So I'm trying to launch my server in pycharm using pserve. This works when I run a cmd window and do `pserve "C:\Users\Desktop\Test Project\development.ini"`
 But now I want to launch this from pycharm so I can debug but when I add the paramters pycharm won't launch my server because python can't open `pserve`.

I'm assuming since it's using python as the interpreter it will always launch everything using python `C:/Python27/python.exe <scripts/parameters>`

Is there a way to get pycharm to launch my server without using `python.exe pserve` or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't realize there was an `.exe` version of the python file pserve-script.py which I should've been using